# Add Two FirebaseListAdapter in one Recylerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

Every User in my Firebase Database has created a group and were added in a Group :

```
(UserID)z.B(IOPFNV5423890)
      • groups
          • created
              • (groupID)
                    • name (name)
                    • timestamp (usw...)

          • added
              • (groupID)
                    • name (name)
                    • (.....)
```

And now I have only one FirebaseListAdapter :

```
final ListUserFirebaseAdapter firebaseAdapter = new ListUserFirebaseAdapter(mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("users/" + userModel.getId() + "/groups/created"), "", this);


 firebaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                int friendlyMessageCount = firebaseAdapter.getItemCount();
                int lastVisiblePosition = mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                        (positionStart >= (friendlyMessageCount - 1) &&
                                lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                    rvListMessage.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
                }
            }
        });
```

Here I set the adapter to the RecyclerView :

```
rvListMessage.setAdapter(firebaseAdapter);
```

But With this Code I can only can set One Adapter but I want to set this Adapter also :

```
 final ListUserFirebaseAdapter firebaseAdapter1 = new ListUserFirebaseAdapter(mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("users/" + userModel.getId() + "/groups/added"), "", this);

   firebaseAdapter1.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                int friendlyMessageCount = firebaseAdapter1.getItemCount();
                int lastVisiblePosition = mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                        (positionStart >= (friendlyMessageCount - 1) &&
                                lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                }
            }
        });
```

My Question now : How can i set the two adapter in one RecyclerView or how can i do it , that both childs (created ; added ) were displayed in one RecyclerView ?

Comment: A RecyclerView can only be based on a single adapter. In addition: a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter can only be based on a single reference/query.

Comment: And how can i make this than ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add two RecyclerView in one Activity or Fragment, one about other, and display "created" in one and "added" in another